# Can't connect with SSL certificate

Tags: ruby, ssl, https, openssl, ssl-certificate

I've pfx sectificate, with which I have to log into a specific URL to send and receive data. It's self-signed certificate.

Made `pem` files:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in client_ssl.pfx -out client_smsgate-in.pem -clcerts
openssl pkcs12 -in client_ssl.pfx -out ca_client_smsgate-in.pem -cacerts
```

Try connections:

```
require "net/https"
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("myurl.ru")
pem = File.read("client_smsgate-in.pem")
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)

http.use_ssl = true
http.ca_file = File.read("ca_client_smsgate-in.pem")
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER

http.cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(pem)
http.key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(pem, 'pass')

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)
response = http.request(request)
```

I've error:
`lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in 'connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)`

If check `OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE`, it works. tell me what's wrong, because I have CA certificates to him?

Comment: Is the server certificate for `myurl.ru` also signed with `ca_client_smsgate-in.pem` or only the client certificate?

Comment: @slowjack2k, yes, the server certificate for `myurl.ru` signed with `ca_client_smsgate-i‌​n.pem`

Comment: Did you examine `ca_client_smsgate-in.pem` is every thing ok with this file? Maybe `http.set_debug_output($stdout) ` give some hints.

Comment: @slowjack2k, `http.set_debug_output($stdout)` - `opening connection to myurl.ru:9443...
opened
starting SSL for myurl.ru:9443...
SSL established
Conn close because of connect error SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown  state: certificate verify failed /home/dev/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http.rb:923:in `connect': SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: certificate verify failed (OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError)`. In google chrome: `There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID).` What could be the problem?

Comment: What's the Common Name of your cert and ca?

Comment: @slowjack2k, The certificate CN = mysite.ru, and I in the code referring to ip address, such as 1.1.1.1. This Name (mysite.ru) not resolved in the network. Linked to this the problem?

Comment: Yes, when you use the ip address directly to connect and not the domain name, then this is an issue for ssl. You can use the ip-address as CN in this case.